# string builder or html tag builder for html. which is efficient?

Tags: asp.net, html, performance, stringbuilder

I normally use string builder to construct html dynamically in codebehind and write it to Dom. I never used htmlbuilder to build html in codebehind so far. Recently saw some of our projects are using htmlbuilder. My question is, I feel comfort building html in stringbuilder. Since there is htmlbuilder specifically for that, please let me know which is efficient for constructing dynamic html and writing to dom. Also, their advantages over one another for constructing dynamic html.

Also, performance wise which is better?

Comment: are you referring to TagBuilder?

Comment: Yes am referring to html tag builder class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are refferring to the `TagBuilder` class it uses a `StringBuilder` internally

```
/// <summary>
    /// Renders the HTML tag by using the specified render mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// The rendered HTML tag.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="renderMode">The render mode.</param>
    public string ToString(TagRenderMode renderMode)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      switch (renderMode)
      {
        case TagRenderMode.StartTag:
          sb.Append('<').Append(this.TagName);
          this.AppendAttributes(sb);
          sb.Append('>');
          break;
        case TagRenderMode.EndTag:
          sb.Append("</").Append(this.TagName).Append('>');
          break;
        case TagRenderMode.SelfClosing:
          sb.Append('<').Append(this.TagName);
          this.AppendAttributes(sb);
          sb.Append(" />");
          break;
        default:
          sb.Append('<').Append(this.TagName);
          this.AppendAttributes(sb);
          sb.Append('>').Append(this.InnerHtml).Append("</").Append(this.TagName).Append('>');
          break;
      }
      return ((object) sb).ToString();
    }
```

So basically the only difference is that it provides some nice ways to target certain html specific things like ids, open closing tags etc.

I would suggest you are best off using this instead of using the stringbuilder directly as it going to make it less likely you make errors with the html tags

Comment: Actually I feel reading the code and debugging the content is more likely when i use string builder. I also want to know, by performance perspective which is better for creating large dynamic html content?

Comment: @Moniecorleone As Daniel stated, the TagBuilder uses a StringBuilder internally.. the performance question is void.

Comment: So the only difference is, way of implementing?

Comment: A TagBuilder needs to figure out how to render what you tell it; imperative code telling a StringBuilder precisely what to do is likely to be simpler and more straight-forward, requiring fewer CPU cycles and most importantly, fewer branches (ifs, switches and loops). Branching is the most CPU-expensive thing in this code and an opportunity for optimization when writing StringBuilder-based code. You might also know roughly how long the string would be which is a major savings in memory pressure/copying. The StringBuilder wins in many scenarios, and at worst, ties.